# Run tag doesn't support data binding in WP7?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, data-binding

Today I tried to use something like,  and the Blend complained that there's invalid xaml. I am pretty sure this works in Silverlight 3/4...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind the Text property by default in WP7. Here is a workaround: [Databinding TextBlock Runs in Silverlight / WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253622/databinding-textblock-runs-in-silverlight-wp7)

Comment: thanks for this. creating an attached property for this might be a lit bit too much, i will just create another TextBlock i think. :)