# Data binding the Text property of a Run

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to databind a `Run` of a `TextBlock` in code at runtime, and I can't for the life of me figure out how.

Several sources on the internet suggest this isn't possible without some (not too pretty) additional workarounds, and, more importantly, it should completely fail when you try to do it in XAML.

Yet, in my application I have the following, which works beautifully:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PitchTemplate">
    <Grid Width="120" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   TextAlignment="Center">
            <Run Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}" FontSize="36"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Frequency, StringFormat=\{0:n2\}Hz}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

So I figured: If it can be done in XAML, it should be possible to do it in code.

Sofar, to no avail. Using the "regular" way of binding in code won't work; the `Run` class doesn't inherit from `FrameworkElement`, so doesn't have a `SetBinding` method, and it's `Text` property is not a `DependencyProperty`.

Using `BindingOperations.SetBinding` doesn't work because the `Text` property is not a `DependencyProperty`.

I'm up to the point that I'm willing to accept that it can't be done at runtime (although not without a last attempt at StackOverflow), but I'm still curious if

- This can be done in code at runtime?

And if not:

- How come it does work in XAML?

**EDIT:**

The example shown is just there to show that it *can* be done in XAML. The reason I need to create the bindings in code, is that I have a control that dynamically creates other elements, which need to be data bound.

**UPDATE:**

As Pete and I both found out, there *is* a dependency property for `Text`, but it's private. I assume that's why it does work through XAML (the xaml parser probably has more rights when it comes to reflection, and more knowledge in general about classes).

The upside is, that this means (tried & tested) it also works through XamlReader.Load(), which is (sofar) the cleanest solution I've come up with.

But if anyone has anything better, I'd be glad to hear about it.

Comment: Ah yes, I should've explained. It's a different scenario for which I need the binding to be done in code, where controls are generated dynamically. The accompanying example was just to show that it can be done in XAML. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks both to Pete & Panagiotis for their efforts and suggestions (both 1 up).

In the end, I decided to go with my own solution (found in the "Update" section of the question): Create dedicated XAML strings containing the `Run` including the binding, and use XamlReader.Load() to parse it, and return a `Run` object.

The situation I'm working on is quite specific, so a local solution to the problem is good enough (for now). Reflection, as suggested by Panagiotis, won't work due to restrictions imposed by Silverlight. Lastly, the [`BindableRuns`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253622/databinding-textblock-runs-in-silverlight-wp7) solutions would need either extensive work to deal with nested properties, or I would have to "uglify" my view model, so I discarded it (also for now).

Thanks all for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Run.Text is backed by the private TextProperty which means you can't directly set its value without some reflection gimmicks, something like this:

```
        Run r=new Run();
        r.Text = "Moo";
        var field=r.GetType().GetField("TextProperty", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var dp=field.GetValue(null) as DependencyProperty;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(r, dp, new Binding {...});
```

This is rather ugly, but perhaps it can be useful.

You can find various workarounds for this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253622/databinding-textblock-runs-in-silverlight-wp7) SO post uses a custom attached property to configure binding. The attached property is used because Run is a sealed class in Silverlight so you can't create you own Run that supports binding.

Comment: Unfortunately (and AFAIK), reflection doesn't work with private fields in Windows Phone, but I will try to be sure (it's just a ugly as my current solution anyways ;) ). Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, I saw the attached property solution before, but was not very enchanted by it. Most likely because then I still had hopes that there would be a "normal" solution ;). I might switch to that anyway if it turns out be a more common problem.

Comment: I've decided to go for my own solution (as explained in my own answer). Thanks for your efforts, and suggestions (1 up).

Answer (score 1):

The reason that it works in XAML but not in code-behind might be that there is a dependency property for Text, but it is private. It's a little bit 'black magic' to me though, so that's just a guess! This is a strange one, as in WPF the Run does inherit from FrameworkContentElement and has a SetBinding method...

Could you create a subclass of Run that contains a public DependencyProperty for text? I'm afraid I don't have the Silverlight dev tools to hand to try it out at the moment, but I'll try and take a look later.

Comment: Yup, while reflecting through the silverlight libraries, I found the private Text dependency property too. It *is* probably why it works from XAML. The Run class is sealed, so no sub classing. The slightly good part however is that it also works with XamlReader.Load(). So until a better solution comes up, I will work with that.

Comment: Rats, it's not sealed in WPF either. There's the problem with trying to answer questions without a test platform!

Comment: Restrictions, restrictions...it can sometimes be a nightmare to navigate between the different XAML platforms :(

Comment: I've decided to go for my own solution (as explained in my own answer). Thanks for your efforts, and suggestions (1 up).