# How can I format text in a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am trying to make a single block of text composed of multiple `TextBlock`s

**- THE TARGET**

For example, I want to achieve like the line below:

- "I read this line in a *ListBox*, notice the multiple **text formatting**"

The way I'm trying to do is

```
<StcakPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" >

   <TextBlock Text="I read this line in a " TextWrapping="Wrap" />
   <TextBlock Text="ListBox"  FontStyle="Italic" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
   <TextBlock Text=", notice the multiple " TextWrapping="Wrap" />
   <TextBlock Text="text formatting" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

<StcakPanel>
```

**- THE PROBLEM**

The text does not fit in the StackPanel, despite of setting TextWrapping for TextBlocks and Width for StackPanel.

I want to generate this code at runtime. I don't know how many words do I need to format.

Kind of showing SearchResults with highlighted search keywords.

**- THE QUESTION**

How can the above target be achieved either using StackPanel or something else? Having the following constraints.

- The text length is unknown
- The number of textblocks in the stackpanel is unknown
- width and height is Unknown

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a single `<TextBlock>` which can contain multiple `<Run>`s that can each have their own formatting. If you want to insert a linebreak, you can use the `<Linebreak />` control.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" >
    <TextBlock>
       <Run Text="I read this line in a" />
       <Run Text="ListBox" FontStyle="Italic" />
       <Run Text=", notice the multiple" />
       <Run Text="text formatting" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </TextBlock>
<StackPanel>
```

At that point you probably don't even need the `<StackPanel>` unless you are going to have multiple `<TextBlocks>` stacked on top of one another.

See this post for more information and examples: http://www.danderson.me/posts/working-with-the-wpf-textblock-control/

---

To databind multiple runs within a TextBlock, see this answer: [Databinding TextBlock Runs in Silverlight / WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253622/databinding-textblock-runs-in-silverlight-wp7)

Comment: How can I do this at run time? Can I use multiple RUNs at runtime?

Comment: You can insert Runs as children of a TextBlock at runtime. See my edit for how to do this, or just add the controls yourself manually with code similar to `myTextBlock.Children.Add(new Run());`