# WPF StackPanel ToolTip Binding Failing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code in my WPF XAML file:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CustomersViewModel}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Customer">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                   
                    <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding}">                            
                        <StackPanel.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                       Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}">                   
                                    <TextBlock>
                                    <Run Text="Customer Name: "/>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </StackPanel.ToolTip>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/> 
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BirthDate}"/>


                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>



 public ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> CustomersViewModel
```

I added the ToolTip DataContext property and now the crash is gone but it does not bind to anything and the FullName comes out to be empty. The StackPanel is inside the Datagrid which is defined below:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

UPDATE:

```
  public partial class CustomersScreen : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> _customersViewModel;

        public CustomersScreen ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _customersViewModel= new ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>()
                {
                    new CustomerViewModel() { FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "Kate", City="Houston", State="Texas", BirthDate = "12/19/2981"}, 
                    new CustomerViewModel() { FirstName = "John", LastName="Doe", City="Austin", State="Texas", BirthDate = "03/01/2001"}
                };


            this.DataContext = _customersViewModel; 
        }

        public ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> CustomersViewModel
        {
            get { return _customersViewModel; }

        }
    }
```

Comment: if you just use a simple text instead of `{Binding FullName}`, it works OK, so it must be something wrong with the Binding. That means you need to post more code, about your Binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your viewmodel should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the `FullName` property like this:

```
public class CustomViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
   public CustomViewModel(){
      //....
   }
   protected event PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged;
   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property){
      var handler = propertyChanged;
      if(handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
   }
   event INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged {
      add { propertyChanged += value; }
      remove { propertyChanged -= value;}
   }
   public string FullName { 
      get { 
           return String.Format("{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName);
      } 
   }
   string firstName;
   string lastName; 
   public string FirstName {
     get { return firstName;}
     set {
        if(firstName != value){
           firstName = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
           //also trigger PropertyChanged for FullName
           OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
     }
   }
   public string LastName {
     get { return lastName;}
     set {
        if(lastName != value){
           lastName = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
           //also trigger PropertyChanged for FullName
           OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it still hangs on that screen. I have updated my question with more code which might help.

Comment: @johndoe you don't have any DataContext outside? I thought you had a one, if not you have to set the `DataContext` for your `StackPanel` like this `DataContext="{Binding}"`

Comment: But I am setting the ItemsSource of the Datagrid property. ItemsSource is a collection which contains CustomerViewModel object. I need to bind each row of grid to a CustomerViewModel object in the Tooltip.

Comment: @johndoe you just need to set the `DataContext="{Binding}"` for the `StackPanel`, it will get the current binding (attached to the current item).

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I did now but still no use. Still it throws some exception and the screen feezes. I am not explicitly setting the Tooltip datacontext since it will inherit from StackPanel. I have updated the code to show the current code.

Comment: @johndoe looks like it has another problem somewhere else. The code you posted does not look like it can freeze the screen. At first I just thought it's the problem of showing the ToolTip. There is something wrong with your code elsewhere.

Comment: It is problem with binding the Tooltip with FullName. If I remove that and replace it with constant string it works fine.

Comment: @johndoe you can try viewing the ***Output*** window to see if there is any useful message there (I doubt it should involve the string **FullName** there).

Comment: Nothing in the Output window. I updated the original code to attach the code behind where I do the binding maybe the issue is there.

Comment: @johndoe where is the `FullName` property in your ViewModel? I just see the `FirstName` and the `LastName`.

Comment: FullName just returns the concatenated version of FirstName and LastName

Comment: I am thinking that StackPanel DataContext is set the the collection instead of the individual CustomerViewModel item which is why it is not able to find the FullName property.

Comment: @johndoe but your viewmodel does not have any property `FullName`. It should exist. If you want to concatenate the FirstName and the LastName, you should use MultiBinding as in the updated code.

Comment: I do have a FullName property in the ViewModel defined as follows:     public string FullName
        {
            get { return String.Format("{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName); }
        } I don't want to use MultiBinding because it looks ugly in XAML. If I bind to FirstName then it works but with FullName it does not work. This is extremely confusing!

Comment: @johndoe looks like it's a problem of notifying property changed, I hope you know about `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Really weird because I bind to the FullName inside the DataTemplate of DataGridTemplateColumn and it works fine. But inside the StackPanel for tooltip it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will check out INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @johndoe try viewing the code I updated about implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the `FullName`, `PropertyChanged` should be triggered whenever `FirstName` or `LastName` is changed.

Comment: Turns out it was because the binding cannot work for readonly properties unless they are OneWay. I changed it to OneWay and now everything works. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Run is NOT a frameworkelement so cannot be bound to.

See if this thread offers a solution.

[Databinding TextBlock Runs in Silverlight / WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253622/databinding-textblock-runs-in-silverlight-wp7)

Regards

Comment: `Text` in `Run` is a `DependencyProperty` thus making it bindable.